# How to remove set off string in PHP

Tags: php

I have this string variable in  my PHP code:
I am getting this value from DB.

```
$includes = "~ All taxes<br/>~ Complimentary Buffet Breakfast,<br/>~ Complimentary Wi-Fi<br/>~ Complimentary Fruit Basket only for Suite Room<br/><br/>Facilities and Services:<br/>~ 24Hrs Room Service<br/>~ Lounge<br/>~ Direct Dialing STD and ISD facilities <br/>Kindly Note:<br/>Before 72Hrs Cancellation full refund";
```

How to remove this sentence ('Kindly Note: Before 72Hrs Cancellation full refund') from the string.
I have to remove the text which come after this text('Kindly Note:') from the given string How to do that.
Some time I get different text after this text('Kindly Note: We dont allow 24hrs checkin') So I want to remove text whatever comes after this text('Kindly Note:');

Comment: Is this a dynamic text or a static one?

Comment: Text looks static... Why don't you just remove it right there?

Comment: @MyWay it is dynamic comes from DB

Comment: there are lots of ways trim, str_replace, but we need to know exactly what you want to establish here, so we could help you

Comment: Hey @MyWay I want to remove this sentence (Kindly Note:<br/>Before 72Hrs Cancellation full refund) from the string.

Comment: if this is a static content, you can just change the string. Else you should know the algorithm of how this string is created.

Comment: [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) should be what you need.

Comment: @MyWay this string(Kindly Note:<br/>Before 72Hrs Cancellation full refund) come always at the end of the string.

Comment: you need to give us more examples of what might be the values of $includes

Comment: @NSNoob I tried that but the requirement is that I have to remove what ever come after this text(Kindly Note:) from the given string How to achieve that

Comment: this is the first time I see 7 answers within 13 mins O.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I love exploding things...try this logic, will **remove anything beyond** the "Kindly Note:" part:

```
$includes = "~ All taxes<br/>~ Complimentary Buffet Breakfast,<br/>~ Complimentary Wi-Fi<br/>~ Complimentary Fruit Basket only for Suite Room<br/><br/>Facilities and Services:<br/>~ 24Hrs Room Service<br/>~ Lounge<br/>~ Direct Dialing STD and ISD facilities <br/>Kindly Note:<br/>Before 72Hrs Cancellation full refund";
$arr_includes = explode('Kindly Note:', $includes);
$include = $arr_includes[0];
```

output:

> ~ All taxes
> ~ Complimentary Buffet Breakfast,
> ~ Complimentary Wi-Fi
> ~ Complimentary Fruit Basket only for Suite Room
> Facilities and Services:
> ~ 24Hrs Room Service
> ~ Lounge
> ~ Direct Dialing STD and ISD facilities

Comment: And before run this logic it will be better if you check 'Kindly Note:' is there in the string or not.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh yeah, thanks :)

Comment: @Ceeee It helped a lot man thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

use [chop()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_chop.asp)

```
echo chop($includes,'Before 72Hrs Cancellation full refund');
```

or

```
echo chop($includes,'Kindly Note:<br/>Before 72Hrs Cancellation full refund');
```

**Edit 1**

use

```
echo substr($includes, 0, strpos($includes, "Kindly Note:"));
```

Comment: Pls read question again the requirement is different

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use **str_replace** simply.

```
str_replace('Kindly Note:<br/>Before 72Hrs Cancellation full refund', '', $includes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
 if ($dbText === 'your text') {
     $dbText = 'your replacement text';
 }
```

or change the text in the database itself. If you need something else, please elaborate on your requirements. Things like string replacement or regular expression replacement come to mind for more generic problems.

Answer (score 0):

If it comes always end of the string the you can use

```
substr($string, 0, -3);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `str_replace` function

```
$s = "~ All taxes<br/>~ Complimentary Buffet Breakfast,<br/>~ Complimentary Wi-Fi<br/>~ Complimentary Fruit Basket only for Suite Room<br/><br/>Facilities and Services:<br/>~ 24Hrs Room Service<br/>~ Lounge<br/>~ Direct Dialing STD and ISD facilities <br/>Kindly Note:<br/>Before 72Hrs Cancellation full refund";

$new_string =  str_replace('<br/>Kindly Note:<br/>Before 72Hrs Cancellation full refund', '', $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume `"Kindly Note:"` exists in the string and you want to remove anything after the `"Kindly Note:"`

```
echo strstr($includes, "Kindly Note:", true);
```